# Design FIR filter with half zero coefficions

Tags: finite-impulse-response, decimation

I noticed a lot of hardware IC use special FIR filters with half zero of coefficients to minimize multiplication operations, especially in decimators/interpolators. E.g.

[ 6 0 -19 0 47 0 -100 0 192 0 -342 0 572 0 -914 0 1409 0 -2119 0 3152 0 -4729 0 7420 0 -13334 0 41527 65536 41527 0 -13334 0 7420  0 -4729 0 3152 0 -2119 0 1409 0 -914 0 572 0 -342 0 192 0 -100 0 47 0 -19 0 6]

or

[-12 0 84 0 -336 0 1006 0 -2691 0 10141 16384 10141 0 -2691 0 1006 0 -336 0 84 0 -12]

I took these coefficients from IC datasheet. I see the center coefficient is 0.5 and other odd coefficients are zero. It effectively halves the mul operations.

But I can't find what the type of the FIR filter is. Is there any good paper? How to create a filter with desired number of taps with this feature?

Comment: It's often a truncated sinc half band filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, these are "Nyquist (M) filters", in your case M=2. You'll very often find them in mutlirate systems, especially as L-th-band-filters (i.e. filters that only let through 1/L of the Nyquist bandwidth) in decimators.

This is very fundamental for multirate systems, not really "research paper stuff", so your best bet is hence a good book on Multirate Systems. Fliege has written a classic "Multirate Digital Signal Processing", harris did, too, with "Multirate Signal Processing For Communication Systems" and Vaidyanathan seems to have written a popular book called "Multirate Systems and Filter Banks", but I haven't ever read that.

Comment: Marcus, Thank you very much for the books reference. I was able to get Fliege's and found it very good not just for my case but in general multirate system understanding!

Comment: @sergfc glad to hear that!